# Android preference fragment taking space for icon in list preference fragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment

[image]

As you can see in the image, it is taking some additional space in left . Later I have found that this space is assigned for icon. How can I remove this space?

I have tried  `preference.setIcon(null);`

Also I have tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198014/preferencefragmentcompat-padding-issue-with-style-preferencethemeoverlay) . But no luck .

I am using     `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.1.1'`

**Edit**

Here is my `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlayCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceThemeOverlayCustom" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/PreferenceFragmentListCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceFragmentListCustom" parent="PreferenceFragmentList">

    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="paddingStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: why down vote ? Whats the reason?

Comment: try a new sample project in Android studio with template "Settings Activity" and see if it works there first what you want to achieve

Comment: If anyone is still facing this problem I recommend downgrading your preference library to implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:27.1.1'. This fixed it for me. I guess some kind of problem in the version between 27.1.1 and 28.0.0 occured

Answer (score 2):

Constructing the new preference like this:

`new Preference(getPreferenceScreen().getContext());`

should solve the issue.

As mentioned by guillaume-tgl the explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32457928/5799699).

*Edit:*
Using the new support library (28.0.0) you should also call:

`preference.setIconSpaceReserved(false);`

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452412/new-preference-support-library-incorrect-theme-at-runtime

Comment: You're right. This is the solution: "preference.setIconSpaceReserved(false);"

Answer (score 1):

Just add `app:iconSpaceReserved="false"` line to your XML file and now there won't be any space from start.

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to the PreferenceThemeOverlay that you are using for that activity.
Your selected style taking default padding from left or right.

use this code

```
<style name="" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you share your style and layout xml , so  i will  explain

Comment: try this ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)lv.getParent();
parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);